# Using the identity column to add a value to a computed column

Tags: sql, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2016

At times I need to store a temporary value to a field. I have a stored procedure that adds it using:

```
Insert new record first then

SELECT @Record_Value = SCOPE_IDENTITY(); 

UPDATE ADMIN_Publication_JSON
SET NonPubID = CAST(@Record_Value as nvarchar(20)) + '_tmp'
WHERE RecID = @Record_Value
```

It simply takes the identity value and adds an '_tmp' to the end. Is there a way that I can create a default value in the table that would do that automatically if I did not insert a value into that field?

The `NonPubID` column is just a `NVARCHAR(50)`.

Thanks

Comment: For inserts, a `DEFAULT` clause will do. For updates, a trigger will do. Both can use a sequence, not an identity.

Comment: I don't want to use it as an identity but I want to use the identity column in some way to add a default value into the NVARCHAR(50) field or should I just leave it in my stored proc?

Comment: @user1314159 . . . Do you want to set `NonPubId` to any other value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could write a trigger, that replaces `NULL` with that string upon `INSERT`.

```
CREATE TRIGGER admin_publication_json_bi
               ON admin_publication_json
               AFTER INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  SET NOCOUNT ON;

  UPDATE apj
         SET apj.nonpubid = concat(convert(varchar(20), i.id), '_tmp')
         FROM admin_publication_json apj
              INNER JOIN inserted i
                         ON i.id = apj.id
         WHERE i.nonpubid IS NULL;
END;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2012&fiddle=227136049d3a13db99d4c2ae26c9eef2)

Downside: You cannot explicitly insert `NULL`s for that column, should that be desired.

Comment: Thanks-- I like your code and I think I will give it a try

Comment: A little change -- but I still like your code and I could give it a try but I think I'm going to stick with code in the Stored Procedure because I have a little bit better control how to handle to data coming it.  Such as if it is a book reference I could use "_001" or a plain article nothing ""  or maybe a blog post "_blog" .  Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

Check out NewKey col below:

```
CREATE TABLE #Table
(
   ID INT NOT NULL IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED,
   IDValue VARCHAR(1) ,
   ModifiedDT DATETIME NULL,   
   NewKey AS ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),ID)+'_Tmp' )
)

INSERT   #Table( IDValue, ModifiedDT ) 
SELECT   'A', GETDATE()
UNION ALL
SELECT   'Y', GETDATE() - 1
UNION ALL
SELECT   'N', GETDATE() - 5

SELECT * FROM #Table
```

Comment: This means `NewKey` cannot be updated though. The OP has not specified, so this may be a good answer, but personally, I suspect from the `_tmp` that the OP does actually want to update the column.

Comment: Sorry- I was not clear but yes the column is normally inserted with the correct value.  However; at times the correct value is not currently available so I wanted to use the identity columns value plus the _tmp so all I have to do later is remove the _tmp and I know what record needs to be updated with the correct value

Comment: Well, I do not understand why you would want to do this even though I provided the answer above. Your RecID column is non null and non-updatable column type because it is an identity column. Whatever you are storing in NonPubId column can always be established from  ID+'_tmp', so no need for extra column. I surely must be missing something!

Comment: 95% of the time I have the Publication ID from the Government Website PubMed.  These are articles that are written by Researchers.  The numbers look like 25465297 or 26190575.  These numbers are stored in a NVARCHAR(50) field because other values must be added if the article is not published at PubMed.  These are made up on the fly such as a Book or a Video or a Blog post.  Anything that the Researcher wants credit for.  The Table has a column that identifies what type of entry it is.

Comment: The tmp is for all other types of research and instead of making up an number or using a guid or anything else I was trying to use the record id with a _tmp.  Does that help?

Comment: Got it. Thanks. You can also add addtl case statements in the newKey logic to further govern when a NewKey is populated with a value. Like NewKey AS (case when PubId is null then ( CONVERT(VARCHAR(100),ID)+'_Tmp' ) else .... END)

Comment: Thanks-- I think I'm going to stick with code in the Stored Procedure because I have a little bit better control how to handle to data coming it.  Thanks again